# Cognos graph - specifying styles based on the value of a different dimension

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-11

I have been given complex requirements for a line chart.  Here it is mocked-up manually in Excel:

[image: Complex Chart Example]

Using Cognos Analytics 11.0.13, but plan to upgrade to 11.1.7 soon.

I want to draw a line chart with two lines.  Using the samples data from Cognos, the chart will show Revenue as the measure, Date along the x-axis, and Order Method Type as the line color.  At this point, which colors are used is not critical.  Also, show all days even if there is no data.  Sounds simple so far.

The tricky bits:
If it's a weekend the line should be dashed, otherwise it should be solid.
If Region is Americas, the marker should be green, otherwise it should be red.

Can this be done natively in Cognos, or am I looking at developing a Custom Control using d3?

Here's the current state of the attempt:

```
<report xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/report/14.3/" expressionLocale="en" useStyleVersion="11.4">
    <drillBehavior/>
    <layouts>
        <layout>
            <reportPages>
                <page name="Page1">
                    <style>
                        <defaultStyles>
                            <defaultStyle refStyle="pg"/>
                        </defaultStyles>
                    </style>
                    <pageBody>
                        <style>
                            <defaultStyles>
                                <defaultStyle refStyle="pb"/>
                            </defaultStyles>
                        </style>
                        <contents>
                            <v2_combinationChart maxHotspots="10000" name="Combination chart1" refQuery="output">
                                <v2_combinationTypeTooltips/>
                                <v2_legend>
                                    <v2_legendPosition>
                                        <v2_legendPreset/>
                                    </v2_legendPosition>
                                    <v2_legendTitle refQuery="output">
                                        <v2_chartTextContents>
                                            <v2_automaticText/>
                                        </v2_chartTextContents>
                                        <style>
                                            <defaultStyles>
                                                <defaultStyle refStyle="lx"/>
                                            </defaultStyles>
                                        </style>
                                    </v2_legendTitle>
                                    <style>
                                        <defaultStyles>
                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lg"/>
                                        </defaultStyles>
                                    </style>
                                </v2_legend>
                                <v2_commonAxis>
                                    <v2_ordinalAxis>
                                        <v2_axisTitle refQuery="output">
                                            <v2_chartTextContents>
                                                <v2_automaticText/>
                                            </v2_chartTextContents>
                                            <style>
                                                <defaultStyles>
                                                    <defaultStyle refStyle="at"/>
                                                </defaultStyles>
                                            </style>
                                        </v2_axisTitle>
                                        <v2_axisLine lineWeight="0"/>
                                        <v2_axisLabels>
                                            <style>
                                                <defaultStyles>
                                                    <defaultStyle refStyle="al"/>
                                                </defaultStyles>
                                            </style>
                                        </v2_axisLabels>
                                        <v2_labelControl/>
                                    </v2_ordinalAxis>
                                    <chartNodes>
                                        <chartNode>
                                            <chartNodeMembers>
                                                <chartNodeMember refDataItem="Date">
                                                    <chartContents>
                                                        <chartTextItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <memberCaption/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </chartTextItem>
                                                    </chartContents>
                                                    <sortList>
                                                        <sortItem refDataItem="Date" sortOrder="ascending"/>
                                                    </sortList>
                                                    <propertyList>
                                                        <propertyItem refDataItem="Region"/>
                                                    </propertyList>
                                                </chartNodeMember>
                                            </chartNodeMembers>
                                        </chartNode>
                                    </chartNodes>
                                </v2_commonAxis>
                                <v2_topLeftAxis>
                                    <v2_combinationChartTypes>
                                        <v2_line lineDisplayType="lineAndMarkers">
                                            <v2_linePalette markerSize="5pt">
                                                <v2_linePaletteEntries>
                                                    <v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                                        <v2_lineFill defaultColor="#8599D3">
                                                            <v2_linearGradient>
                                                                <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#8599D3"/>
                                                                <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#5876AE"/>
                                                            </v2_linearGradient>
                                                        </v2_lineFill>
                                                        <v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                                            <v2_fillEffect>
                                                                <v2_linearGradient>
                                                                    <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#8599D3"/>
                                                                    <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#5876AE"/>
                                                                </v2_linearGradient>
                                                            </v2_fillEffect>
                                                        </v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                                    </v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                                    <v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                                        <v2_lineFill defaultColor="#E3AE6C">
                                                            <v2_linearGradient>
                                                                <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#E3AE6C"/>
                                                                <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#CD854E"/>
                                                            </v2_linearGradient>
                                                        </v2_lineFill>
                                                        <v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                                            <v2_fillEffect>
                                                                <v2_linearGradient>
                                                                    <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#E3AE6C"/>
                                                                    <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#CD854E"/>
                                                                </v2_linearGradient>
                                                            </v2_fillEffect>
                                                        </v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                                    </v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                                    <v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                                        <v2_lineFill defaultColor="#839862">
                                                            <v2_linearGradient>
                                                                <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#839862"/>
                                                                <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#6C7F56"/>
                                                            </v2_linearGradient>
                                                        </v2_lineFill>
                                                        <v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                                            <v2_fillEffect>
                                                                <v2_linearGradient>
                                                                    <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#839862"/>
                                                                    <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#6C7F56"/>
                                                                </v2_linearGradient>
                                                            </v2_fillEffect>
                                                        </v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                                    </v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                                    <v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                                        <v2_lineFill defaultColor="#B7C873">
                                                            <v2_linearGradient>
                                                                <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#B7C873"/>
                                                                <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#AFB885"/>
                                                            </v2_linearGradient>
                                                        </v2_lineFill>
                                                        <v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                                            <v2_fillEffect>
                                                                <v2_linearGradient>
                                                                    <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#B7C873"/>
                                                                    <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#AFB885"/>
                                                                </v2_linearGradient>
                                                            </v2_fillEffect>
                                                        </v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                                    </v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                                    <v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                                        <v2_lineFill defaultColor="#8484A8">
                                                            <v2_linearGradient>
                                                                <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#8484A8"/>
                                                                <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#525E7E"/>
                                                            </v2_linearGradient>
                                                        </v2_lineFill>
                                                        <v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                                            <v2_fillEffect>
                                                                <v2_linearGradient>
                                                                    <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#8484A8"/>
                                                                    <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#525E7E"/>
                                                                </v2_linearGradient>
                                                            </v2_fillEffect>
                                                        </v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                                    </v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                                    <v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                                        <v2_lineFill defaultColor="#C0CCED">
                                                            <v2_linearGradient>
                                                                <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#C0CCED"/>
                                                                <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#B0C2E5"/>
                                                            </v2_linearGradient>
                                                        </v2_lineFill>
                                                        <v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                                            <v2_fillEffect>
                                                                <v2_linearGradient>
                                                                    <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#C0CCED"/>
                                                                    <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#B0C2E5"/>
                                                                </v2_linearGradient>
                                                            </v2_fillEffect>
                                                        </v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                                    </v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                                    <v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                                        <v2_lineFill defaultColor="#8C5580">
                                                            <v2_linearGradient>
                                                                <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#8C5580"/>
                                                                <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#794067"/>
                                                            </v2_linearGradient>
                                                        </v2_lineFill>
                                                        <v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                                            <v2_fillEffect>
                                                                <v2_linearGradient>
                                                                    <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#8C5580"/>
                                                                    <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#794067"/>
                                                                </v2_linearGradient>
                                                            </v2_fillEffect>
                                                        </v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                                    </v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                                    <v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                                        <v2_lineFill defaultColor="#C789BC">
                                                            <v2_linearGradient>
                                                                <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#C789BC"/>
                                                                <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#BB72BC"/>
                                                            </v2_linearGradient>
                                                        </v2_lineFill>
                                                        <v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                                            <v2_fillEffect>
                                                                <v2_linearGradient>
                                                                    <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#C789BC"/>
                                                                    <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#BB72BC"/>
                                                                </v2_linearGradient>
                                                            </v2_fillEffect>
                                                        </v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                                    </v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                                    <v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                                        <v2_lineFill defaultColor="#D5BAEF">
                                                            <v2_linearGradient>
                                                                <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#D5BAEF"/>
                                                                <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#C29FD1"/>
                                                            </v2_linearGradient>
                                                        </v2_lineFill>
                                                        <v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                                            <v2_fillEffect>
                                                                <v2_linearGradient>
                                                                    <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#D5BAEF"/>
                                                                    <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#C29FD1"/>
                                                                </v2_linearGradient>
                                                            </v2_fillEffect>
                                                        </v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                                    </v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                                    <v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                                        <v2_lineFill defaultColor="#83683F">
                                                            <v2_linearGradient>
                                                                <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#83683F"/>
                                                                <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#604926"/>
                                                            </v2_linearGradient>
                                                        </v2_lineFill>
                                                        <v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                                            <v2_fillEffect>
                                                                <v2_linearGradient>
                                                                    <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#83683F"/>
                                                                    <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#604926"/>
                                                                </v2_linearGradient>
                                                            </v2_fillEffect>
                                                        </v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                                    </v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                                    <v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                                        <v2_lineFill defaultColor="#DCB05A">
                                                            <v2_linearGradient>
                                                                <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#DCB05A"/>
                                                                <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#C09C52"/>
                                                            </v2_linearGradient>
                                                        </v2_lineFill>
                                                        <v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                                            <v2_fillEffect>
                                                                <v2_linearGradient>
                                                                    <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#DCB05A"/>
                                                                    <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#C09C52"/>
                                                                </v2_linearGradient>
                                                            </v2_fillEffect>
                                                        </v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                                    </v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                                    <v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                                        <v2_lineFill defaultColor="#F4DF9E">
                                                            <v2_linearGradient>
                                                                <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#F4DF9E"/>
                                                                <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#E4CF87"/>
                                                            </v2_linearGradient>
                                                        </v2_lineFill>
                                                        <v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                                            <v2_fillEffect>
                                                                <v2_linearGradient>
                                                                    <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#F4DF9E"/>
                                                                    <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#E4CF87"/>
                                                                </v2_linearGradient>
                                                            </v2_fillEffect>
                                                        </v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                                    </v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                                    <v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                                        <v2_lineFill defaultColor="#5F8A8C">
                                                            <v2_linearGradient>
                                                                <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#5F8A8C"/>
                                                                <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#537579"/>
                                                            </v2_linearGradient>
                                                        </v2_lineFill>
                                                        <v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                                            <v2_fillEffect>
                                                                <v2_linearGradient>
                                                                    <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#5F8A8C"/>
                                                                    <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#537579"/>
                                                                </v2_linearGradient>
                                                            </v2_fillEffect>
                                                        </v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                                    </v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                                    <v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                                        <v2_lineFill defaultColor="#96C4B2">
                                                            <v2_linearGradient>
                                                                <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#96C4B2"/>
                                                                <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#89B0A0"/>
                                                            </v2_linearGradient>
                                                        </v2_lineFill>
                                                        <v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                                            <v2_fillEffect>
                                                                <v2_linearGradient>
                                                                    <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#96C4B2"/>
                                                                    <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#89B0A0"/>
                                                                </v2_linearGradient>
                                                            </v2_fillEffect>
                                                        </v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                                    </v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                                    <v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                                        <v2_lineFill defaultColor="#CBE8E7">
                                                            <v2_linearGradient>
                                                                <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#CBE8E7"/>
                                                                <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#BDD6D5"/>
                                                            </v2_linearGradient>
                                                        </v2_lineFill>
                                                        <v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                                            <v2_fillEffect>
                                                                <v2_linearGradient>
                                                                    <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#CBE8E7"/>
                                                                    <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#BDD6D5"/>
                                                                </v2_linearGradient>
                                                            </v2_fillEffect>
                                                        </v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                                    </v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                                    <v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                                        <v2_lineFill defaultColor="#AE6564">
                                                            <v2_linearGradient>
                                                                <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#AE6564"/>
                                                                <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#875352"/>
                                                            </v2_linearGradient>
                                                        </v2_lineFill>
                                                        <v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                                            <v2_fillEffect>
                                                                <v2_linearGradient>
                                                                    <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#AE6564"/>
                                                                    <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#875352"/>
                                                                </v2_linearGradient>
                                                            </v2_fillEffect>
                                                        </v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                                    </v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                                    <v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                                        <v2_lineFill defaultColor="#D88C6F">
                                                            <v2_linearGradient>
                                                                <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#D88C6F"/>
                                                                <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#C47D61"/>
                                                            </v2_linearGradient>
                                                        </v2_lineFill>
                                                        <v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                                            <v2_fillEffect>
                                                                <v2_linearGradient>
                                                                    <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#D88C6F"/>
                                                                    <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#C47D61"/>
                                                                </v2_linearGradient>
                                                            </v2_fillEffect>
                                                        </v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                                    </v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                                    <v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                                        <v2_lineFill defaultColor="#E3C9B0">
                                                            <v2_linearGradient>
                                                                <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#E3C9B0"/>
                                                                <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#D2B2A5"/>
                                                            </v2_linearGradient>
                                                        </v2_lineFill>
                                                        <v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                                            <v2_fillEffect>
                                                                <v2_linearGradient>
                                                                    <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#E3C9B0"/>
                                                                    <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#D2B2A5"/>
                                                                </v2_linearGradient>
                                                            </v2_fillEffect>
                                                        </v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                                    </v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                                    <v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                                        <v2_lineFill defaultColor="#848484">
                                                            <v2_linearGradient>
                                                                <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#848484"/>
                                                                <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#555555"/>
                                                            </v2_linearGradient>
                                                        </v2_lineFill>
                                                        <v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                                            <v2_fillEffect>
                                                                <v2_linearGradient>
                                                                    <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#848484"/>
                                                                    <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#555555"/>
                                                                </v2_linearGradient>
                                                            </v2_fillEffect>
                                                        </v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                                    </v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                                    <v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                                        <v2_lineFill defaultColor="#a4a4a4">
                                                            <v2_linearGradient>
                                                                <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#a4a4a4"/>
                                                                <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#909090"/>
                                                            </v2_linearGradient>
                                                        </v2_lineFill>
                                                        <v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                                            <v2_fillEffect>
                                                                <v2_linearGradient>
                                                                    <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#a4a4a4"/>
                                                                    <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#909090"/>
                                                                </v2_linearGradient>
                                                            </v2_fillEffect>
                                                        </v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                                    </v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                                    <v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                                        <v2_lineFill defaultColor="#C7C7C7">
                                                            <v2_linearGradient>
                                                                <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#C7C7C7"/>
                                                                <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#c1c1c1"/>
                                                            </v2_linearGradient>
                                                        </v2_lineFill>
                                                        <v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                                            <v2_fillEffect>
                                                                <v2_linearGradient>
                                                                    <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#C7C7C7"/>
                                                                    <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#c1c1c1"/>
                                                                </v2_linearGradient>
                                                            </v2_fillEffect>
                                                        </v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                                    </v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                                </v2_linePaletteEntries>
                                            </v2_linePalette>
                                            <v2_conditionalLinePalette showInLegend="hide">
                                                <v2_lineAdvancedCondition>
                                                    <v2_lineCases>
                                                        <v2_lineCase>
                                                            <v2_conditionalPaletteEntryLabel>
                                                                <v2_automaticLabel/>
                                                            </v2_conditionalPaletteEntryLabel>
                                                            <reportCondition>_day_of_week ([output].[Date],1) in (6,7) and [output].[Order method type]='E-mail' and [output].[Region] = 'Americas'</reportCondition>
                                                            <v2_linePaletteEntry lineStyle="dash">
                                                                <v2_lineFill defaultColor="#198545">
                                                                    <v2_color color="#8599D3"/>
                                                                </v2_lineFill>
                                                                <v2_pointPaletteEntry markerShape="circle">
                                                                    <v2_fillEffect defaultColor="#198545">
                                                                        <v2_solidColor color="blue"/>
                                                                    </v2_fillEffect>
                                                                </v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                                            </v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                                        </v2_lineCase>
                                                    </v2_lineCases>
                                                </v2_lineAdvancedCondition>
                                                <v2_lineAdvancedCondition>
                                                    <v2_lineCases>
                                                        <v2_lineCase>
                                                            <reportCondition>_day_of_week ([output].[Date],1) in (6,7) and [output].[Order method type]='Telephone' and [output].[Region] = 'Americas'</reportCondition>
                                                            <v2_linePaletteEntry lineStyle="dash">
                                                                <v2_lineFill defaultColor="#198545">
                                                                    <v2_color color="#E3AE6C"/>
                                                                </v2_lineFill>
                                                                <v2_pointPaletteEntry markerShape="circle">
                                                                    <v2_fillEffect defaultColor="#198545">
                                                                        <v2_solidColor color="blue"/>
                                                                    </v2_fillEffect>
                                                                </v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                                            </v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                                        </v2_lineCase>
                                                    </v2_lineCases>
                                                </v2_lineAdvancedCondition>
                                            </v2_conditionalLinePalette>
                                            <chartNodes>
                                                <chartNode>
                                                    <chartNodeMembers>
                                                        <chartNodeMember refDataItem="Order method type">
                                                            <chartContents>
                                                                <chartTextItem>
                                                                    <dataSource>
                                                                        <memberCaption/>
                                                                    </dataSource>
                                                                </chartTextItem>
                                                            </chartContents>
                                                        </chartNodeMember>
                                                    </chartNodeMembers>
                                                </chartNode>
                                            </chartNodes>
                                        </v2_line>
                                    </v2_combinationChartTypes>
                                    <v2_axis>
                                        <v2_axisTitle refQuery="output">
                                            <v2_chartTextContents>
                                                <v2_automaticText/>
                                            </v2_chartTextContents>
                                            <style>
                                                <defaultStyles>
                                                    <defaultStyle refStyle="at"/>
                                                </defaultStyles>
                                            </style>
                                        </v2_axisTitle>
                                        <v2_axisLine lineWeight="0"/>
                                        <v2_axisRange>
                                            <v2_automaticRange/>
                                        </v2_axisRange>
                                        <v2_axisLabels>
                                            <style>
                                                <defaultStyles>
                                                    <defaultStyle refStyle="al"/>
                                                </defaultStyles>
                                            </style>
                                        </v2_axisLabels>
                                        <v2_majorGridlines lineWeight="0" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                                    </v2_axis>
                                </v2_topLeftAxis>
                                <style>
                                    <defaultStyles>
                                        <defaultStyle refStyle="ch"/>
                                    </defaultStyles>
                                    <CSS value="width:1054px;height:365px"/>
                                </style>
                                <noDataHandler>
                                    <contents>
                                        <block>
                                            <contents>
                                                <textItem>
                                                    <dataSource>
                                                        <staticValue>No Data Available</staticValue>
                                                    </dataSource>
                                                </textItem>
                                            </contents>
                                            <style>
                                                <CSS value="padding:16px;"/>
                                            </style>
                                        </block>
                                    </contents>
                                </noDataHandler>
                                <v2_defaultChartMeasure refDataItem="Revenue"/>
                            </v2_combinationChart>
                        </contents>
                    </pageBody>
                </page>
            </reportPages>
        </layout>
    </layouts>
    <queries>
        <query name="source">
            <source>
                <model/>
            </source>
            <selection>
                <dataItem aggregate="total" name="Revenue">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Sales].[Revenue]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="2"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="2"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_isCurrency" value="true"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Date">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Time].[Date]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="4"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Day of the week">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Time].[Day of the week]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="1"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Order method type">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Order method].[Order method type]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="3"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem name="Region" aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Retailers].[Region]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute name="RS_dataType" value="3" output="no"/>
                        <XMLAttribute name="RS_dataUsage" value="0" output="no"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem name="join" aggregate="none">
                    <expression>'a'</expression>
                </dataItem>
            </selection>
            <detailFilters>
                <detailFilter>
                    <filterExpression>[Order method type] in ('E-mail','Telephone')</filterExpression>
                </detailFilter>
                <detailFilter>
                    <filterExpression>[Date]&lt;= 2010-02-28</filterExpression>
                </detailFilter>
            </detailFilters>
        </query>
        <query name="date">
            <source>
                <model/>
            </source>
            <selection>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Date">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Time].[Date]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="4"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Day of the week">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Time].[Day of the week]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="1"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem name="join" aggregate="none">
                    <expression>'a'</expression>
                </dataItem>
            </selection>
            <detailFilters>
                <detailFilter>
                    <filterExpression>[Date]&lt;= 2010-02-28</filterExpression>
                </detailFilter>
            </detailFilters>
        </query>
        <query name="dimensions">
            <source>
                <joinOperation>
                    <joinOperands>
                        <joinOperand cardinality="1:1">
                            <queryRef refQuery="source"/>
                        </joinOperand>
                        <joinOperand cardinality="1:1">
                            <queryRef refQuery="date"/>
                        </joinOperand>
                    </joinOperands>
                    <joinFilter>
                        <filterExpression>[source].[join] = [date].[join]</filterExpression>
                    </joinFilter>
                </joinOperation>
            </source>
            <selection>
                <dataItem name="Date" aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none">
                    <expression>[date].[Date]</expression>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem name="Day of the week" aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none">
                    <expression>[date].[Day of the week]</expression>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem name="Order method type" aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none">
                    <expression>[source].[Order method type]</expression>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem name="Region" aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none">
                    <expression>[source].[Region]</expression>
                </dataItem>
            </selection>
        </query>
        <query name="output">
            <source>
                <joinOperation>
                    <joinOperands>
                        <joinOperand cardinality="0:1">
                            <queryRef refQuery="source"/>
                        </joinOperand>
                        <joinOperand cardinality="1:1">
                            <queryRef refQuery="dimensions"/>
                        </joinOperand>
                    </joinOperands>
                    <joinFilter>
                        <filterExpression>[source].[Date] = [dimensions].[Date] and [source].[Order method type] = [dimensions].[Order method type] and [source].[Region] = [dimensions].[Region]</filterExpression>
                    </joinFilter>
                </joinOperation>
            </source>
            <selection>
                <dataItem name="Date" aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none">
                    <expression>[dimensions].[Date]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute name="RS_dataType" value="4" output="no"/>
                        <XMLAttribute name="RS_dataUsage" value="0" output="no"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem name="Day of the week" aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none">
                    <expression>[dimensions].[Day of the week]</expression>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem name="Order method type" aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none">
                    <expression>[dimensions].[Order method type]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute name="RS_dataType" value="3" output="no"/>
                        <XMLAttribute name="RS_dataUsage" value="0" output="no"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem name="Region" aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none">
                    <expression>[dimensions].[Region]</expression>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem name="Revenue" aggregate="total" rollupAggregate="automatic">
                    <expression>[source].[Revenue]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute name="RS_dataType" value="2" output="no"/>
                        <XMLAttribute name="RS_dataUsage" value="2" output="no"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
            </selection>
        </query>
    </queries>
    <XMLAttributes>
        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_CreateExtendedDataItems" value="true"/>
        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="listSeparator" value=","/>
        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="decimalSeparator" value="."/>
        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_modelModificationTime" value="2015-11-25T21:38:24.820Z"/>
    </XMLAttributes>
    <modelPath type="FM">/content/folder[@name='Samples']/folder[@name='Models']/package[@name='GO sales (query)']/model[@name='model']</modelPath>
</report>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the legacy charts, you can use a conditional pallete on the measure.  The following example uses the day_of_week field to apply it to the date.  I used the properties property to ensure the day_of_week is included in the query given its not projected.

```
<report xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/report/15.5/"           expressionLocale="en" useStyleVersion="11.6">
            
            <drillBehavior/>
            <layouts>
                <layout>
                    <reportPages>
                        <page name="Page1">
                            <style>
                                <defaultStyles>
                                    <defaultStyle refStyle="pg"/>
                                </defaultStyles>
                            </style>
                            <pageBody>
                                <style>
                                    <defaultStyles>
                                        <defaultStyle refStyle="pb"/>
                                    </defaultStyles>
                                </style>
                                <contents><v2_combinationChart maxHotspots="10000" name="Combination chart1" refQuery="Query1">
            
            
            
            
            <v2_combinationTypeTooltips/>
            <v2_legend>
                <v2_legendPosition>
                    <v2_legendPreset/>
                </v2_legendPosition>
                <v2_legendTitle refQuery="Query1">
                    <v2_chartTextContents>
                        <v2_automaticText/>
                    </v2_chartTextContents>
                    <style>
                        <defaultStyles>
                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lx"/>
                        </defaultStyles>
                    </style>
                </v2_legendTitle>
                <style>
                    <defaultStyles>
                        <defaultStyle refStyle="lg"/>
                    </defaultStyles>
                </style>
            </v2_legend>
            <v2_commonAxis>
                <v2_ordinalAxis>
                    <v2_axisTitle refQuery="Query1">
                        <v2_chartTextContents>
                            <v2_automaticText/>
                        </v2_chartTextContents>
                        <style>
                            <defaultStyles>
                                <defaultStyle refStyle="at"/>
                            </defaultStyles>
                        </style>
                    </v2_axisTitle>
                    <v2_axisLine lineWeight="0"/>
                    <v2_axisLabels>
                        <style>
                            <defaultStyles>
                                <defaultStyle refStyle="al"/>
                            </defaultStyles>
                        </style>
                    </v2_axisLabels>
                <v2_labelControl/></v2_ordinalAxis>
            <chartNodes><chartNode><chartNodeMembers><chartNodeMember refDataItem="Date"><chartContents><chartTextItem><dataSource><memberCaption/></dataSource></chartTextItem></chartContents></chartNodeMember></chartNodeMembers></chartNode></chartNodes></v2_commonAxis>
            <v2_topLeftAxis>
                <v2_combinationChartTypes>
                    <v2_line>
                        <v2_linePalette markerSize="5pt">
                            
                        <v2_linePaletteEntries><v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                    <v2_lineFill defaultColor="#8599D3">
                                        <v2_linearGradient>
                                            <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#8599D3"/>
                                            <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#5876AE"/>
                                        </v2_linearGradient>
                                    </v2_lineFill>
                                    <v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                        <v2_fillEffect>
                                            <v2_linearGradient>
                                                <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#8599D3"/>
                                                <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#5876AE"/>
                                            </v2_linearGradient>
                                        </v2_fillEffect>
                                    </v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                </v2_linePaletteEntry><v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                    <v2_lineFill defaultColor="#E3AE6C">
                                        <v2_linearGradient>
                                            <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#E3AE6C"/>
                                            <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#CD854E"/>
                                        </v2_linearGradient>
                                    </v2_lineFill>
                                    <v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                        <v2_fillEffect>
                                            <v2_linearGradient>
                                                <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#E3AE6C"/>
                                                <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#CD854E"/>
                                            </v2_linearGradient>
                                        </v2_fillEffect>
                                    </v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                </v2_linePaletteEntry><v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                    <v2_lineFill defaultColor="#839862">
                                        <v2_linearGradient>
                                            <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#839862"/>
                                            <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#6C7F56"/>
                                        </v2_linearGradient>
                                    </v2_lineFill>
                                    <v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                        <v2_fillEffect>
                                            <v2_linearGradient>
                                                <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#839862"/>
                                                <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#6C7F56"/>
                                            </v2_linearGradient>
                                        </v2_fillEffect>
                                    </v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                </v2_linePaletteEntry><v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                    <v2_lineFill defaultColor="#B7C873">
                                        <v2_linearGradient>
                                            <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#B7C873"/>
                                            <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#AFB885"/>
                                        </v2_linearGradient>
                                    </v2_lineFill>
                                    <v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                        <v2_fillEffect>
                                            <v2_linearGradient>
                                                <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#B7C873"/>
                                                <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#AFB885"/>
                                            </v2_linearGradient>
                                        </v2_fillEffect>
                                    </v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                </v2_linePaletteEntry><v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                    <v2_lineFill defaultColor="#8484A8">
                                        <v2_linearGradient>
                                            <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#8484A8"/>
                                            <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#525E7E"/>
                                        </v2_linearGradient>
                                    </v2_lineFill>
                                    <v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                        <v2_fillEffect>
                                            <v2_linearGradient>
                                                <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#8484A8"/>
                                                <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#525E7E"/>
                                            </v2_linearGradient>
                                        </v2_fillEffect>
                                    </v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                </v2_linePaletteEntry><v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                    <v2_lineFill defaultColor="#C0CCED">
                                        <v2_linearGradient>
                                            <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#C0CCED"/>
                                            <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#B0C2E5"/>
                                        </v2_linearGradient>
                                    </v2_lineFill>
                                    <v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                        <v2_fillEffect>
                                            <v2_linearGradient>
                                                <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#C0CCED"/>
                                                <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#B0C2E5"/>
                                            </v2_linearGradient>
                                        </v2_fillEffect>
                                    </v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                </v2_linePaletteEntry><v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                    <v2_lineFill defaultColor="#8C5580">
                                        <v2_linearGradient>
                                            <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#8C5580"/>
                                            <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#794067"/>
                                        </v2_linearGradient>
                                    </v2_lineFill>
                                    <v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                        <v2_fillEffect>
                                            <v2_linearGradient>
                                                <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#8C5580"/>
                                                <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#794067"/>
                                            </v2_linearGradient>
                                        </v2_fillEffect>
                                    </v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                </v2_linePaletteEntry><v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                    <v2_lineFill defaultColor="#C789BC">
                                        <v2_linearGradient>
                                            <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#C789BC"/>
                                            <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#BB72BC"/>
                                        </v2_linearGradient>
                                    </v2_lineFill>
                                    <v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                        <v2_fillEffect>
                                            <v2_linearGradient>
                                                <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#C789BC"/>
                                                <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#BB72BC"/>
                                            </v2_linearGradient>
                                        </v2_fillEffect>
                                    </v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                </v2_linePaletteEntry><v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                    <v2_lineFill defaultColor="#D5BAEF">
                                        <v2_linearGradient>
                                            <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#D5BAEF"/>
                                            <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#C29FD1"/>
                                        </v2_linearGradient>
                                    </v2_lineFill>
                                    <v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                        <v2_fillEffect>
                                            <v2_linearGradient>
                                                <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#D5BAEF"/>
                                                <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#C29FD1"/>
                                            </v2_linearGradient>
                                        </v2_fillEffect>
                                    </v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                </v2_linePaletteEntry><v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                    <v2_lineFill defaultColor="#83683F">
                                        <v2_linearGradient>
                                            <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#83683F"/>
                                            <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#604926"/>
                                        </v2_linearGradient>
                                    </v2_lineFill>
                                    <v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                        <v2_fillEffect>
                                            <v2_linearGradient>
                                                <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#83683F"/>
                                                <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#604926"/>
                                            </v2_linearGradient>
                                        </v2_fillEffect>
                                    </v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                </v2_linePaletteEntry><v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                    <v2_lineFill defaultColor="#DCB05A">
                                        <v2_linearGradient>
                                            <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#DCB05A"/>
                                            <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#C09C52"/>
                                        </v2_linearGradient>
                                    </v2_lineFill>
                                    <v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                        <v2_fillEffect>
                                            <v2_linearGradient>
                                                <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#DCB05A"/>
                                                <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#C09C52"/>
                                            </v2_linearGradient>
                                        </v2_fillEffect>
                                    </v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                </v2_linePaletteEntry><v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                    <v2_lineFill defaultColor="#F4DF9E">
                                        <v2_linearGradient>
                                            <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#F4DF9E"/>
                                            <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#E4CF87"/>
                                        </v2_linearGradient>
                                    </v2_lineFill>
                                    <v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                        <v2_fillEffect>
                                            <v2_linearGradient>
                                                <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#F4DF9E"/>
                                                <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#E4CF87"/>
                                            </v2_linearGradient>
                                        </v2_fillEffect>
                                    </v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                </v2_linePaletteEntry><v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                    <v2_lineFill defaultColor="#5F8A8C">
                                        <v2_linearGradient>
                                            <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#5F8A8C"/>
                                            <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#537579"/>
                                        </v2_linearGradient>
                                    </v2_lineFill>
                                    <v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                        <v2_fillEffect>
                                            <v2_linearGradient>
                                                <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#5F8A8C"/>
                                                <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#537579"/>
                                            </v2_linearGradient>
                                        </v2_fillEffect>
                                    </v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                </v2_linePaletteEntry><v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                    <v2_lineFill defaultColor="#96C4B2">
                                        <v2_linearGradient>
                                            <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#96C4B2"/>
                                            <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#89B0A0"/>
                                        </v2_linearGradient>
                                    </v2_lineFill>
                                    <v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                        <v2_fillEffect>
                                            <v2_linearGradient>
                                                <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#96C4B2"/>
                                                <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#89B0A0"/>
                                            </v2_linearGradient>
                                        </v2_fillEffect>
                                    </v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                </v2_linePaletteEntry><v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                    <v2_lineFill defaultColor="#CBE8E7">
                                        <v2_linearGradient>
                                            <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#CBE8E7"/>
                                            <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#BDD6D5"/>
                                        </v2_linearGradient>
                                    </v2_lineFill>
                                    <v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                        <v2_fillEffect>
                                            <v2_linearGradient>
                                                <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#CBE8E7"/>
                                                <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#BDD6D5"/>
                                            </v2_linearGradient>
                                        </v2_fillEffect>
                                    </v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                </v2_linePaletteEntry><v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                    <v2_lineFill defaultColor="#AE6564">
                                        <v2_linearGradient>
                                            <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#AE6564"/>
                                            <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#875352"/>
                                        </v2_linearGradient>
                                    </v2_lineFill>
                                    <v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                        <v2_fillEffect>
                                            <v2_linearGradient>
                                                <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#AE6564"/>
                                                <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#875352"/>
                                            </v2_linearGradient>
                                        </v2_fillEffect>
                                    </v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                </v2_linePaletteEntry><v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                    <v2_lineFill defaultColor="#D88C6F">
                                        <v2_linearGradient>
                                            <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#D88C6F"/>
                                            <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#C47D61"/>
                                        </v2_linearGradient>
                                    </v2_lineFill>
                                    <v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                        <v2_fillEffect>
                                            <v2_linearGradient>
                                                <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#D88C6F"/>
                                                <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#C47D61"/>
                                            </v2_linearGradient>
                                        </v2_fillEffect>
                                    </v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                </v2_linePaletteEntry><v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                    <v2_lineFill defaultColor="#E3C9B0">
                                        <v2_linearGradient>
                                            <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#E3C9B0"/>
                                            <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#D2B2A5"/>
                                        </v2_linearGradient>
                                    </v2_lineFill>
                                    <v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                        <v2_fillEffect>
                                            <v2_linearGradient>
                                                <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#E3C9B0"/>
                                                <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#D2B2A5"/>
                                            </v2_linearGradient>
                                        </v2_fillEffect>
                                    </v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                </v2_linePaletteEntry><v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                    <v2_lineFill defaultColor="#848484">
                                        <v2_linearGradient>
                                            <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#848484"/>
                                            <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#555555"/>
                                        </v2_linearGradient>
                                    </v2_lineFill>
                                    <v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                        <v2_fillEffect>
                                            <v2_linearGradient>
                                                <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#848484"/>
                                                <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#555555"/>
                                            </v2_linearGradient>
                                        </v2_fillEffect>
                                    </v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                </v2_linePaletteEntry><v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                    <v2_lineFill defaultColor="#a4a4a4">
                                        <v2_linearGradient>
                                            <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#a4a4a4"/>
                                            <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#909090"/>
                                        </v2_linearGradient>
                                    </v2_lineFill>
                                    <v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                        <v2_fillEffect>
                                            <v2_linearGradient>
                                                <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#a4a4a4"/>
                                                <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#909090"/>
                                            </v2_linearGradient>
                                        </v2_fillEffect>
                                    </v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                </v2_linePaletteEntry><v2_linePaletteEntry>
                                    <v2_lineFill defaultColor="#C7C7C7">
                                        <v2_linearGradient>
                                            <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#C7C7C7"/>
                                            <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#c1c1c1"/>
                                        </v2_linearGradient>
                                    </v2_lineFill>
                                    <v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                        <v2_fillEffect>
                                            <v2_linearGradient>
                                                <v2_gradientColor gradientColor="#C7C7C7"/>
                                                <v2_gradientColor colorPosition="100" gradientColor="#c1c1c1"/>
                                            </v2_linearGradient>
                                        </v2_fillEffect>
                                    </v2_pointPaletteEntry>
                                </v2_linePaletteEntry></v2_linePaletteEntries></v2_linePalette>
                        
                    <v2_conditionalLinePalette showInLegend="hide"><v2_lineAdvancedCondition><v2_lineCases><v2_lineCase><v2_conditionalPaletteEntryLabel><v2_automaticLabel/></v2_conditionalPaletteEntryLabel><reportCondition>_day_of_week ([Query1].[Date],1) in (6,7) and [Query1].[Order method type]=&apos;E-mail&apos;</reportCondition><v2_linePaletteEntry lineStyle="dash"><v2_lineFill defaultColor="#198545"><v2_color color="#8599D3"/></v2_lineFill><v2_pointPaletteEntry><v2_fillEffect defaultColor="#198545"><v2_solidColor color="#198545"/></v2_fillEffect></v2_pointPaletteEntry></v2_linePaletteEntry></v2_lineCase></v2_lineCases></v2_lineAdvancedCondition><v2_lineAdvancedCondition><v2_lineCases><v2_lineCase><reportCondition>_day_of_week ([Query1].[Date],1) in (6,7) and [Query1].[Order method type]=&apos;Telephone&apos;</reportCondition><v2_linePaletteEntry lineStyle="dash"><v2_lineFill defaultColor="#198545"><v2_color color="#E3AE6C"/></v2_lineFill><v2_pointPaletteEntry><v2_fillEffect defaultColor="#198545"><v2_solidColor color="#198545"/></v2_fillEffect></v2_pointPaletteEntry></v2_linePaletteEntry></v2_lineCase></v2_lineCases></v2_lineAdvancedCondition></v2_conditionalLinePalette><chartNodes><chartNode><chartNodeMembers><chartNodeMember refDataItem="Order method type"><chartContents><chartTextItem><dataSource><memberCaption/></dataSource></chartTextItem></chartContents></chartNodeMember></chartNodeMembers></chartNode></chartNodes></v2_line>
                </v2_combinationChartTypes>
                <v2_axis>
                    <v2_axisTitle refQuery="Query1">
                        <v2_chartTextContents>
                            <v2_automaticText/>
                        </v2_chartTextContents>
                        <style>
                            <defaultStyles>
                                <defaultStyle refStyle="at"/>
                            </defaultStyles>
                        </style>
                    </v2_axisTitle>
                    <v2_axisLine lineWeight="0"/>
                    <v2_axisRange>
                        <v2_automaticRange/>
                    </v2_axisRange>
                    <v2_axisLabels>
                        <style>
                            <defaultStyles>
                                <defaultStyle refStyle="al"/>
                            </defaultStyles>
                        </style>
                    </v2_axisLabels>
                    <v2_majorGridlines lineWeight="0" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                </v2_axis>
            </v2_topLeftAxis>
            <style>
                <defaultStyles>
                    <defaultStyle refStyle="ch"/>
                </defaultStyles>
            <CSS value="width:5000px"/></style>
            <noDataHandler>
                <contents>
                    <block>
                        <contents>
                            <textItem>
                                <dataSource>
                                    <staticValue>No Data Available</staticValue>
                                </dataSource>
                            </textItem>
                        </contents>
                        <style>
                            <CSS value="padding:16px;"/>
                        </style>
                    </block>
                </contents>
            </noDataHandler>
        <v2_defaultChartMeasure refDataItem="Revenue"/></v2_combinationChart></contents>
                            </pageBody>
                        </page>
                    </reportPages>
                </layout>
            </layouts>
        <queries><query name="Query1"><source><model/></source><selection><dataItem aggregate="total" name="Revenue"><expression>[Sales (query)].[Sales].[Revenue]</expression><XMLAttributes><XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="2"/><XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="2"/><XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_isCurrency" value="true"/></XMLAttributes></dataItem><dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Date"><expression>[Sales (query)].[Time].[Date]</expression><XMLAttributes><XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="4"/><XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/></XMLAttributes></dataItem><dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Day of the week"><expression>[Sales (query)].[Time].[Day of the week]</expression><XMLAttributes><XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="1"/><XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/></XMLAttributes></dataItem><dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Order method type"><expression>[Sales (query)].[Order method].[Order method type]</expression><XMLAttributes><XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="3"/><XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/></XMLAttributes></dataItem></selection><detailFilters><detailFilter><filterExpression>[Order method type] in (&apos;E-mail&apos;,&apos;Telephone&apos;)</filterExpression></detailFilter><detailFilter><filterExpression>[Date]&lt;= 2010-02-28</filterExpression></detailFilter></detailFilters></query></queries><XMLAttributes><XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_CreateExtendedDataItems" value="true"/><XMLAttribute output="no" name="listSeparator" value=","/><XMLAttribute output="no" name="decimalSeparator" value="."/><XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_modelModificationTime" value="2013-01-08T15:32:22.123Z"/></XMLAttributes><modelPath>/content/folder[@name=&apos;Samples_LG_DQ&apos;]/folder[@name=&apos;Models&apos;]/package[@name=&apos;GO Sales (query)&apos;]/model[@name=&apos;model&apos;]</modelPath></report>
```

Comment: The example goes against the Go Sales(query) package.  If you get a version error when copying the report into reporting just adjust the schema version to match.

Comment: The key was setting the Properties property of the Chart Node Member of the Categories Chart Node.  (The data item in the x-axis.)

Comment: I was too quick to judge.  Your solution is not complex enough.  You have only two dimensions -- date and day of week.  As soon as I add another dimension (like Reason) I can't distinguish between Reasons on weekends.  Once I add the last dimension (Status) to color the markers, I can't distinguish between reasons anywhere.  This appears to be because none of the graphics settings are optional.  The conditional palette always wins over the primary axis palette for all elements (fill, style, marker color).

Comment: If I concatenate values for my conditional palette, I get two values for each date.  The first one in alphabetical order wins, so both "lines" are formatted the same.  Still can't distinguish between the Reasons.

Comment: To clarify:  This may be something that can be done with much hacking by a high-performing report developer.  But the presentation style requested is something that just makes sense and should be simple for a report developer at any skill level (and Tableau does it natively).  It's looking like a custom visualization will be required.

Comment: This shouldn't require any hacking nor a custom visualization.  I've altered the spec above to use a report expression to grab the weekend days, removing the requirement of the properties property.  I've added order method as the dimension and extended the conditional pallet condition to look for days 6,7 and E-mail/Telephone.   The date field being used has some data holes, but the approach is there.

Comment: Here's what I mean by your solution being too simple:  Adding one more layer of complexity causes problems.  I took your current spec and added markers and tried to color them blue if [Retailers].[Region] = 'Americas' and red if it's not.  It doesn't seem to work.  Maybe I'm doing something wrong.  I'm updating my question with a report spec.  It's basically yours, but displaying every day and a failed attempt to color the markers by an additional dimension.

Comment: If you started with the spec I recently posted, you could reduce it to only the XML tags that contain changes...?  Like the chart and the related conditional styles (or whatever else was involved)

Comment: The chart tags are still 9K above the posting limit.  Send me an email and I'll reply with the spec.